# Can I edit the main.workflow github-actions file locally?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

If I change my `main.workflow` file locally, not in the `master` branch, the commit and push the change, I get this error from `push` command:

```
> git diff
diff --git a/.github/main.workflow b/.github/main.workflow
index 135d8ea..0a13a28 100644
--- a/.github/main.workflow
+++ b/.github/main.workflow
@@ -6,7 +6,7 @@ workflow "Build and Test in PR" {
   ]
 }

-action ".NET Core CLI" {
+action ".NET Core CLI"  {
   uses = "./.github/net-core/"
   args = "test"
 }

> git push
! [remote rejected] my-branch -> my-branch (refusing to allow an integration to create or update .github/main.workflow)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/my-user-name/my-repo.git'
```

Comment: sorry, can't reproduce that.
Any chance you're using GitHub Desktop to push? It can't handle `main.workflow`s as of now.

Comment: @maxheld The problem may be with the repositories settings in Github.

Answer (score 7):

Still experiencing this, even with `.yml` workflow files. Turns out that for me it was due to me using an HTTPS remote instead of SSH.

To work around this issue in the Github API, I simply used an SSH remote instead of HTTPS.

You can see if you are using HTTPS or SSH by

```sh
$ git remote -v
> origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> origin  https://github.com/USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

Notice if there is a `https://` instead of `git` (SSH).

Then do

```sh
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git
```

Then verify the change

```sh
$ git remote -v
# Verify new remote URL
> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (fetch)
> origin  git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY.git (push)
```

**Further Reading**: Github Docs on [Switching remote URLs from HTTPS to SSH](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/managing-remote-repositories#switching-remote-urls-from-https-to-ssh)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using GitHub desktop there is currently a bug that causes this error when attempting to push commits from GitHub Actions. As a workaround, you can use the Git API until the fix for this issue is released.